# Why is my NSRegularExpression pattern not working?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following string:

```
NSString *string = @"she seemed \x3cem\x3ereluctant\x3c/em\x3e to discuss the matter";
```

I want the final string to be: `"she seemed reluctant to discuss the matter"`

I have the following pattern:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/\\x[0-9a-f]{2}/"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange(matchRange));
}
```

However, I get an error saying the pattern is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure Objective C doesn't require the // delimiter, try without?

Comment: @r3mus you mean like `\\x[0-9a-f]{2}`? Still doesn't work: `NSInvalidValue=\x[0-9a-f]{2}}`

Comment: Even `\\x` doesn't work: `NSInvalidValue=\x`

Comment: Admittedly not at a computer to test - but I think \x is reserved for Unicode. Try escaping it too `\\\x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you need is:

```
@"\\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}"
```

The backslash is special to both Obj-C and the RE parser - so you need to create an Obj-C string with two \'s so the RE parser can then end up with one.

Also there are no open/close delimiters in the string - you're thinking of another programming language there!

Comment: Great thanks that worked. Say now I have a string `emchair/em`. What would be the pattern required that would result in only `chair`, that is to remove the em and /em?

Comment: I suspect your comment lost some characters... Regardless have a go and if it fails to work ask another question showing what you tried - and be specific as to what you're trying to match (just *chair*, any open-tag/text/close-tag sequence, do you expect nested tags, etc.)

Comment: Ok, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415565/regex-pattern-to-find-occurrences-of-html-tags

Answer (score -1):

You can save yourself some regex troubles by using the NSString method

stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:

Or

stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:

Comment: If it helps, those methods use the same under the hood.