# Regex pattern to find occurrences of html tags

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Say I have a string that looks like this:

```
iword/i
```

Here the tag is `i`. This is similar to an HTML tag except without the <> angle brackets.

Or say I have

> emword/em

Here the tag is `em`.

What I want is a pattern that removes these tags.

I'm testing this pattern:

`<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>` on http://rubular.com/, but it is not working properly.

Specifically, what I want to do is with Objective-C:

```
NSString *string = @"iword/i";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) withTemplate:@""];
```

which will just remove all but `word`.

Comment: The example input string is not clear. Are all the things you replace at the end of a newline terminated line?

Comment: Is this part of the same problem as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414673/why-is-my-nsregularexpression-pattern-not-working) or entirely separate? If it is part of the same problem then do it in two phases - angle brackets and then tags - is probably not the best way to do it as you lose the location of the tags. Also are you just trying to remove certain matching pairs, or all html tags? What about tags like <br> (or <br/>) which are singletons?

Comment: Just noticed your regular expression is matching angle brackets, but your question says the angle brackets are not there...

Comment: @CRD the pattern I have up there is just something I found online. My specific case does not need to match angle brackets. And this question is entirely separate from my other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a complete list of html tags you want to remove then (i, em, b, what else?) since you're going to have to search specifically for the tags to remove.

One way of doing this is: `\b(i|em|b)(\w*)\/(i|em|b)\b` (and as you've seen before with Obj-c, likely some double \ escaping)

In action: http://regex101.com/r/qL3cU9

Input:

- iword/i
- emword/em
- bword/b
- ibword/ib
- notgoing/tomatch this

Substitution result:

- word
- word
- word
- ibword/ib
- notgoing/tomatch this

Comment: This is not working with the following code: `NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\b(i|em|b).*\\/(i|em|b)\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) withTemplate:@""];`

Comment: Nothing gets replaced

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have mentioned that this is using capture groups - so you'll need to retrieve and return capture group 2. Also updated to enclose .* in () and updated the regex101 link ($2 in PCRE is the equivalent to capture group 2. Also - you'll probably need to escape \b too: `\\b`

Comment: Hmm ya ended up doing that. But I still can't get it to match properly in Objective-C. Not sure how the syntax would differ in that case.

Comment: So here's the problem: http://regex101.com/r/lA3hW7 . It finds the first occurrence of one of those letters, regardless if it's a part of that tag. What's the solution? Perhaps `[a-z]*` instead of .*? But maybe it can be even more specific than that..

Comment: Yep, needs to be more specific. Didn't know it was JSON, that makes it a lot easier (no }]", in strings). start with `(\w*)` instead of `(.*)` for now, if you need to expand it, use `([\w#_]*)` etc. to match a collection of characters. And, of course, escaped to work in Obj-c.